# MinGW Linking GLFW gets errors

Tags: c++, mingw, glfw

I'm having problems when trying to link GLFW with MinGW.
The code is a simple usage example of GLFW.
I'm running the following command to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -osimple simple.cpp -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -DGLFW_DLL
```

Here's the source code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;

        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
        glEnd();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

MinGW returns a few errors related to undefined references to the GLFW lib functions.

Comment: Try #define `__LCC__` before `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`. If not present, `#define GLFWAPI __declspec(dllimport)` will happen, bringing you `__imp__` "problem".

Comment: Try defining `GLEW_STATIC` above your `#include` statements.

Comment: What are the new errors ? Still the same problem ?

Comment: Do you have `libglfw3.dll` in addition to `glfw3.dll`?

Comment: Yes, I have both libs. The error is "unresolved reference" in the GLFW functions.

Comment: Can you show us the full errors please?

Comment: [This question has similar errors to yours. Maybe the answer there will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171894/cant-compile-easy-source-in-c-and-opengl-glfw-in-linux-in-netbeans).

Comment: Have you linked opengl32? Try defining `GLFW_DLL`?

Comment: Yes, I linked opengl32 and I defined the GLFW_DLL, but with same error.

Comment: Try replacing `-lgflw3` with `glfw3.dll.a` or `d:\path\to\file\glfw3.dll.a` if it's not in the same directory as `simple.cpp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your program with g++ and added the flag -lgdi32 with g++.
I was able to get this working successfully with this option.

typically, if you're compiling with g++, you usually need to have -lglfw3 , -lopengl32 , and lgdi32 . it largely depends, also, on where you've put your libs and headers for glfw.
as long as they're in a folder that gcc/g++ can find, there's typically not any problems compiling and building. without the flags, you'll continue to get the undefined errors.