# Can't link GLFW libs

Tags: c++, linux, glfw, linkage

Everything is pretty much similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171894/cant-compile-easy-source-in-c-and-opengl-glfw-in-linux-in-netbeans) except `glfwInit()` (all other glfw functions still cause linkage error), which is linking normally. When I tried to change 'glfw' to 'glfw3' everything is ok, but application freezes at `glfwCreateWindow()`. I think, I exactly needs '-glfw', not 'glfw3' but it causes linking errors. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two reasons:

1. Linkage error because of presence of deprecated glfw2 libs (just do `sudo apt-get purge libglfw-dev` and `sudo apt-get purge libglfw2` and reinstall libglfw3.
2. Freeze. Yup, this is a [well-known unity bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1383429). You can for example manually retrieve a valid window pointer to use it with glfw. And you also can use for example gnome or mate.