# How to link glew library in Code::Blocks on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, glew

I can't link glew with Code::Blocks. I can't compile with even easy code.
Many errors like`undefined reference to 'glewInit'`.

I have glew library is located in /usr/include/GL/glew.h.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171894/cant-compile-easy-source-in-c-and-opengl-glfw-in-linux-in-netbeans), i guess i ought to link as follows: `-L/usr/local/lib -lglfw3 -pthread -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lrt -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXinerama -lX11`, but i don't know how to do this in Code::Blocks.

Code:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <GLM/glm.hpp>
#else
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GL/glut.h"
#endif

#include <glm/vec3.hpp> // glm::vec3
#include <glm/vec4.hpp> // glm::vec4
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp> // glm::mat4
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp> // glm::translate,    glm::rotate, glm::scale, glm::perspective
#include <math.h>
```

Here is a screenshot of currently linked library:

[image: Here is a screenshot of currently linked library:]

Comment: Did you try to adding those flags to the "other linker options" text box?

Comment: thank you! add them to "other linker options" works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the linker search path. Below is a picture done on **windows platform**, but I believe you will be able to adjust easily to your needs:

[image]

Now, just include your library, as usual:

[image]

and add GLEW to this list (removing, of course, what you dont need)

Comment: Thank you! specify the linker search path works for me, besides, add these library to "other linker options" also works.